# Describe someone who underestimates people's problems

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word or an idiom which describes someone who underestimates people's problems because he/she has got a better position or much more money in his/her life.

Comment: Selfish and/or egotistical.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find any word that means underestimating (or not caring about) somebody else's problems *because* you have a better position. I could underestimate or not care about other people's problems *even though* I'm not at all rich—and that attitude could be expressed by the same word.

Comment: An underestimater!

Comment: @JasonBassford let's consider what i'm about to tell you.for example i'm broke, there is no money to live and i'm talking to my friend who is so rich and i feel so desprate and hopeless then my friend comes up with opinions like "it's not a big deal" in a humaliating way.how can i describe this kinda person? as in my native language we have a proverb meaning a person who doesn't underestand people's situations because she/he has better greater more things

Comment: @AmirRazavi I know what you mean. But anything I can think of is either about the attitude *or* about the money. Not both. I can't think of a single word that clearly means both things at once.

Comment: @JasonBassford i underestand thanks,what about idioms or an informal phrase which menas my explaination?

Answer (score 1):

You could say perhaps: that person is *blasé*.

> bla·sé  (blä-zā′)
>   adj.
>   1. Uninterested because of frequent exposure or indulgence.
>   2. Unconcerned; nonchalant: had a blasé attitude about housecleaning.
>   3. Very sophisticated.
>   — [https://www.thefreedictionary.com/blasé](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/blas%C3%A9)

Answer (score 0):

Such a haughty person showing scornful attitude towards others and considers other's problem(s) as derisory problem(s) can be qualified with following adjectives: *disdainful, Swaggering, and sniffy*.

According to Merriam-Webster

[disdainful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disdainful) (adjective)

> full of or expressing contempt for someone or something regarded as unworthy or inferior.
>
> > "The railway people were disdainful of their customers."

According to vocabulary.com the word ***swaggering*** is defined as:

[Swaggering](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/swaggering) (adjective)

> having or showing arrogant superiority to and disdain of those one views as unworthy
>
> > "But when circumstances force her to return to her “shabby” family’s West Yorkshire estate to help get their financial house in order, her entrepreneurial knowledge and swaggering confidence shock the locals."

[sniffy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sniffy) (adjective) according to Merriam-Webster

> having or expressing a haughty attitude.
>
> > "Britain has always had a sniffy attitude towards craftsmen."